# Why does Nose not see any of my environmental variables?

Tags: python, django, nose

I'm just getting started using Nose and Nosetests and my tests are failing because Nose can't see the environmental variables.

So far, the errors:
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'

I fixed this by exporting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE from .bash_profile

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings"
```

Now I'm seeing:
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'DATABASE_SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS'

Why would iPython and the Django webserver be able to see these ENV variables, but Nose can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alok said, Nose doesn't call BaseDatabaseCreation.create_test_db('None') from django.db.backends.creation so you will need to set this setting manually.

I was not able to get that to work.

However, I found NoseDjango.

Install NoseDjango with:

```
easy_install django-nose
```

Since django-nose extends Django's built-in test command, you should add it to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'django_nose',
...
)
```

Then set TEST_RUNNER in settings.py:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
```

Once NoseDjango is setup you can run your Nose tests via:

```
manage.py test
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently nose [doesn't call](http://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/11777/11777.diff) `create_test_db()` in `django/db/backends/creation.py`, so you are seeing this error.  Just set it to `None`, or call the method yourself.  Not sure if this is fixed in a recent version of Django.

Comment: from django.db.backends.creation import BaseDatabaseCreation; BaseDatabaseCreation.create_test_db('None')   # did not work

Comment: settings in the tests.py:  
DATABASE_SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS = None # did not work either

Comment: I don't know or use Django, but a google search shows http://github.com/inoi/nosedjango/commit/45e9dbd4e59896ae9160e029d92854ce37f4877d, which looks like what you want.